# How to reference ID from other layout

Tags: android

Following [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar) I moved my ActionBar (Toolbar) from my main layout to another layout and I include the toolbar to my main layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.marcelo.notemuevas.MainActivity">
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Servicios"
        android:id="@+id/serviciosTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/serviciosTxt">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my toolbar layout is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But I got the following error
[image]
Why I cant make reference of my toolbar if it has the same id? Can I include my toolbar and make reference so I can put elements below the toolbar?

Edit 1 - Activity Code

```
package com.marcelo.notemuevas;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    String[] itemname ={
            "Carpinteria"
    };
    String[] descripcion={
            "Reparación"
    };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.mipmap.icono1
    };
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        myToolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid, descripcion);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem = itemname[position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, carpinteria.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("key", 5); //Optional parameters
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Edit 2 - Solution

Now I make it work, I added a new Id to the include then I make reference to it like James Lockhart and Phan Văn Linh suggest (dont know why the first time didnt work) so my new question is, the IDs works like variables? only exist where it has been declared?

This is the working xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.marcelo.notemuevas.MainActivity">
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbarLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Servicios"
        android:id="@+id/serviciosTxt"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/serviciosTxt">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but don't the resources of a relative layout need to be at the same level for this to work? You've nested my_toolbar within a linearlayout which is making it one level below. Although I could be wrong.

You could try setting the include to have the id instead

Comment: Im new to Android, I dont understand so much what are you trying to say, but I remove the android:id="@+id/my_toolbar" from the toolbar layout, and I add the id in the include , didnt show errors but the app crash

Comment: @Pulse9, show your `activity` code

Comment: I added the code, everything works if I move the toolbar declaration from toolbar.xml to the acitivy_main.xml but I want to make reference so I can reuse the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML

```
<include
    android:id=@"+id/toolBarLayout" // set the id for layout that contains toolbar
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolBarLayout"> // change my_toolbar to toolBarLayout
```

Then you access to your `Toolbar` by change

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
```

to

```
LinerLayout myLinear = (LinerLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolBarLayout);
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) myLinear.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
```

Comment: Oh yeah, the problem was that, so the ids only work in the same xml?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

1. In your toolbar layout file, in the LinearLayout tag, set the 'android:id' attribute to a unique layout id name, for example: android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
2. Once you have completed (1), in your main layout refer to your toolbar layout file as follows: android:layout_below="@id/toolbarLayout"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did step 1 but when I change         android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar">
 to         android:layout_below="@id/toolbarLayout"> it says that toolbarLayout is not defined anywhere

Comment: Please be advised that when you reference an external layout file, for example layout="@layout/toolbar", the name of that layout file must be toolbar.xml (And it is case sensitive...) Please also check that the R.java class file has been regenerated. The R.java class file is usually a culprit...